# Не получается засетить данные в input

Tags: javascript

Имеется input у которого есть обработчик на keydown

подскажите как засетить этот input чтоб данные подхватились обработчиком.

этот код не работает.

```
function setPrise(el, tmpPrise) {
    el.focus();
    el.select();
    
    let str = (tmpPrise).toString()
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        var evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode':str.charCodeAt(i), 'which':str.charCodeAt(i)});
        el.dispatchEvent(evt);  
        console.log(str.charCodeAt(i)); 
    }
        
    el.blur();
}
```

Абсолютно не понимаю почему не работает :(

Такое чувство что оно курсор не ставит

Comment: Скорее всего не ```document.dispatchEvent(evt);```, а ```el.dispatchEvent(evt);```.

Comment: И скорее всего можно изменить значение поля ввода и потом послать последний символ, не думаю, что кто-то каждый символ записывает в переменную, скорее всего просто считывает значение у поля ввода при каждом нажатии.

Comment: да, поставил так el.dispatchEvent(evt), где el это input, но это не помогло.

Курсор ставит теперь, но символы input всё ровно не ловит

Comment: а зачем создание обработчика в цикле, не пойму.